# How do I iterate/access response headers from a fetch call in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, iterator

Consider the following TS example:

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3000/auth", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // would like to store some information from the response's headers
    // like access tokens etc.

    // Typescript complains about this iteration (see more info below)
    for (var pair of response.headers.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1])
    }

    return response.json()
  })
  // get the response data etc...
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  // log an error etc...
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('ERROR: ', error);
  })
```

Normally, this would be valid but Typescript complains about the iteration and suggests a compiler option:

```
Type 'IterableIterator<[string, string]>' is not an array type or a string type.
Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.
```

Are there any downsides to using `--downlevelIteration`? Is there another way of accomplishing this without having to change the compiler options?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `downlevelIteration` is only for ES3/ES5 targets and you better change your target to ES6+ instead. But yes, changing your compiler options is the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterators (in some languages called Enumerators) were added in ES6. They are not present in ES5 and older. Before ES6 only iterable construct was `Array` or so-called array like native objects. ES6 brought iterators and features like `for ... of` that works with them. When targeting below ES6 you have to use `downlevelIteration` in order to transpile ES6 iterator code to ES5 compatible code (iterator will be changed do `Array`s and `for ... of` will be replaced by ES5 valid syntax). If you are using no other transpiler beside TSC you have no other choice but enable this flag.

Comment: Sort of off topic: I know ES7, 8 and 9 exist. Which is the most stable/common that is being used right now? Do you know?

Answer (score 1):

```
const getHeaders = (headers: Headers) => {
  let headerObj: IObject = {};
  const keys = headers.keys();
    let header = keys.next();
    while (header.value) {
      headerObj[header.value] = headers.get(header.value);
      header = keys.next();
    }
  return headerObj;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> The `Headers.entries()` method returns an iterator allowing to go
> through all key/value pairs contained in this object. Both the key and
> value of each pair are String objects.
> -[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/entries)

```js
const request = new Request("https://api.w3.org/groups");

(async () => {
   let response = await fetch(request);
   for (const entry of response.headers.entries()) {
     console.log(entry[0] + ':' + entry[1]);
   }
   if(response.ok){
      //...
   } else {
      
   }
})().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```